# Accessing untagged text using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using python and beautifulsoup4 to extract some address information.
More specifically, I require assistance when retrieving non-US based zip codes.

Consider the following html data of a US based company: (already a soup object)

```
<div class="compContent curvedBottom" id="companyDescription">
<div class="vcard clearfix">
<p id="adr">
<span class="street-address">999 State St Ste 100</span><br/>
<span class="locality">Salt Lake City,</span>
<span class="region">UT</span>
<span class="zip">84114-0002,</span>
<br/><span class="country-name">United States</span>
</p>
<p>
<span class="tel">
<strong class="type">Phone: </strong>+1-000-000-000
                            </span><br/>
</p>
<p class="companyURL"><a class="url ext" href="http://www.website.com" target="_blank">http://www.website.com</a></p>
</div>

</ul>
</div>
```

I can extract the zipcode (84114-0002) by using the following piece of python code:

```
class CompanyDescription:
    def __init__(self, page):
        self.data = page.find('div', attrs={'id': 'companyDescription'})


    def address(self):
        #TODO: Also retrieve the Zipcode for UK and German based addresses - tricky!
        address = {'street-address': '', 'locality': '', 'region': '', 'zip': '', 'country-name': ''}
        for key in address:
            try:
                adr = self.data.find('p', attrs={'id': 'adr'})
                if adr.find('span', attrs={'class': key}) is None:
                    address[key] = ''
                else:
                    address[key] = adr.find('span', attrs={'class': key}).text.split(',')[0]

                # Attempting to grab another zip code value
                if address['zip'] == '':
                    pass

            except:
                # We should return a dictionary with "" as key adr
                return address

        return address
```

You can see that I need some counsel with line `if address['zip'] == '':`

These two soup object examples are giving me trouble. In the below I would like to retrieve **EC4N 4SA**

```
<div class="compContent curvedBottom" id="companyDescription">
<div class="vcard clearfix">
<p id="adr">
<span class="street-address">Albert Buildings</span><br/>
<span class="extended-address">00 Queen Victoria Street</span>
<span class="locality">London</span>
                                    EC4N 4SA
                                    <span class="region">London</span>
<br/><span class="country-name">England</span>
</p>
<p>
</p>
<p class="companyURL"><a class="url ext" href="http://www.website.com.com" target="_blank">http://www.website.com.com</a></p>
</div>
<p><strong>Line of Business</strong> <br/>Management services, nsk</p> 
</div>
```

as well as below, where I am interested in getting **71364**

```
<div class="compContent curvedBottom" id="companyDescription">
<div class="vcard clearfix">
<p id="adr">
<span class="street-address">Alfred-Kärcher-Str. 100</span><br/>
                                                71364
                                    <span class="locality">Winnenden</span>
<span class="region">Baden-Württemberg</span>
<br/><span class="country-name">Germany</span>
</p>
<p>
<span class="tel">
<strong class="type">Phone: </strong>+00-1234567
                            </span><br/>
<span class="tel"><strong class="type">Fax: </strong>+00-1234567</span>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Now, I am running this program over approximately 68,000 accounts of which 28,000 are non-US based. I have only pulled out two examples of which I know the current method is not bullet proof. There may be other address formats where this script is not working as expected but I believe figuring out UK and German based accounts will help tremendously.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is only text without tag inside `<p>` so you can use

```
find_all(text=True, recursive=False)
```

to get only text (without tags) but not from nested tags (`<span>`).  This gives list with your text and some `\n` and spaces so you can use `join()` to create one string, and `strip()` to remove all `\n` and spaces.

```
data = '''<p id="adr">
<span class="street-address">Albert Buildings</span><br/>
<span class="extended-address">00 Queen Victoria Street</span>
<span class="locality">London</span>
                                    EC4N 4SA
                                    <span class="region">London</span>
<br/><span class="country-name">England</span>
</p>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

soup = BS(data, 'html.parser').find('p')

print(''.join(soup.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)).strip())
```

result: `EC4N 4SA`

The same with second HTML

```
data = '''<p id="adr">
<span class="street-address">Alfred-Kärcher-Str. 100</span><br/>
                                                71364
                                    <span class="locality">Winnenden</span>
<span class="region">Baden-Württemberg</span>
<br/><span class="country-name">Germany</span>
</p>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

soup = BS(data, 'html.parser').find('p')

print(''.join(soup.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)).strip())
```

result: `71364`

Comment: This is beautiful! Thank you @furas I will try this out momentarily. I have not noticed the encompassing <p> tag when looking at this.